# Warning: Unknown block versions being mined! It's possible unknown rules are in effect

Tags: bitcoin-core

Recently, my full node (Bitcoin Core 0.14.2) displays this for both HD and non-HD wallets:

> Warning: Unknown block versions being mined! It's possible unknown rules are in effect

What does this mean?

Comment: Which wallet?  Which version?  Have you upgraded to the latest?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Bitcoin Core 0.14.2 for both HD and non-HD wallets

Comment: even latest bitcoin core wallet 0.17.1 shows the warning :(

Comment: 0.17.1 is not the latest, at the time of this comment the latest is 0.18 and this false warning is completely eliminated from it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Miners have started signalling for BIP 91, which sets bit 4 in version numbers. When BIP 91 activates, it will force miners to set bit 1 (which then indirectly will cause activation of BIP 141 SegWit).

No software release has implemented BIP 91, as a result, it warns because it sees an unknown feature rollout with significant support from miners.

Comment: When you say "no software release" - you mean that no bitcoin core software release has been released recognizing BIP 91 right? This warning is safe to ignore since BIP 91 has no actual change in consensus rules associated with it, right?

Comment: @BT - yes.  BIP91 is informational, essentially.  It triggers BIP148 so requires no support by wallets.

Comment: So will we have to do anything ourselves with respect to this? Are our coins safe by not doing anything at all?

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert at Bitcoin, but here is some of my research:

https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0091.mediawiki

"While this bip (91) is active users should either upgrade to segsignal or wait for additional confirmations when accepting payments."

I guess this is why Bitcoin Core 0.14.2 displays the warning, on my end too.

More:
"BIP91: The SegWit Activation "Kludge" That Should Keep Bitcoin Whole"
https://bitcoinmagazine.com/articles/bip91-segwit-activation-kludge-should-keep-bitcoin-whole/